# Containerize a Web app without source code?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've been tasked to containerize a NodeJS web app without the source code. All i have is the website URL and credentials to access it. Is there a way to write a Dockerfile to containerize this website? I searched all over the internet but couldn't find a way to write a Dockerfile without mentioning the directory of the src code. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I would say that it's not possible. The 'best' I can think of is to spin up a Nginx container, that passes requests on to the Node app. But to do a real containerization of the app, you need access to the source code.

Comment: If you build the application outside Docker, you can `COPY` the built artifact(s) into the image; this is common with Java applications.  But you can't use Docker to create a local copy of a cloud-hosted application without actually having a copy of the program in some form.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that you could get to containerizing a website without the underlying source code would be to crawl the site and put the results into a static webserver.

Website crawling ends up being more complicated than one may imagine, especially if you end up with URLs with lots of get parameters in the URL.

A very crude example to illustrate the concept with an extremely simple website is as follows:

```
FROM alpine as downloader
RUN apk --no-cache add wget
RUN mkdir /output
WORKDIR /output
RUN wget -rnH https://www.example.com/

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=downloader /output /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

```
$ docker build -t examplesitecopy .
$ docker run --name example -d -p 80:80 examplesitecopy
```

Compare the actual https://www.example.com/ to your locally running copy, and it should be the same page as grabbed by wget. Be sure to use `docker build --no-cache` to bust the cache for the `RUN wget ...` step if needed.

If you truly want the nodejs code to run in a container, you'll need to get that code and put it in a container. This example will only make a copy using wget and put it into a containerized nginx static web server. This example does work as it is, but you will certainly need to adapt it if you want to copy a more complicated site: